# Will there be a great migration once the 3D Graphics site opens?

Tags: discussion, migration

Once the [3D Graphics, Modeling & Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications?referrer=jwaHDVlsLyRCxT7Iq4t4JA2) site opens, will there be a lot of questions migrated, or does it really matter?

Questions like

- [Any good screencast for learning blender?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/any-good-screencast-for-learning-blender)
- [How to convert a Maya object to a VBO?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15679/how-to-convert-a-maya-object-to-a-vbo)
- [3DS Max equivalent to vertex weight painting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/3ds-max-equivalent-to-vertex-weight-painting)
- [resource for “Substance Maps” 3ds Max 2012](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16873/resource-for-substance-maps-3ds-max-2012)

Also, will tags like [maya](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maya), [3dsmax](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3dsmax), or [cinema-4d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-4d) be deleted?

Comment: _If_ it opens; it's not even in closed beta yet, and we shouldn't be migrating stuff until at least open beta.

Comment: I like the optimism :)

Comment: 99% and counting...

Comment: @Cyclops awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.  It'll probably be a coordinated effort with whoever the mods on that site are to determine if they want the content.

As far as the tags are concerned, sometimes you're dealing with the export process of certain tools and pipelines, so I'm sure there are plenty of legitimate questions that would have those tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think if the question is reasonably specific to game development it will make sense to be here. Just as there's a "C++ question" and a "C++ in game development" question (the former likely suitable for StackOverflow), there will probably be "Maya" questions and "Maya in game development" questions.

I also think that the proliferation of SE sites with narrower and narrower scope will eventually result in a saturation that prevents more from being kicked off, and in fact I think the newer ones will have to struggle much harder to find a critical mass than the older ones.

Answer (score 2):

[CGI](http://cgi.stackexchange.com/) *is now in private Beta!* 7 days (or more), till it's open to the public.

**Update** - and, now, it's [closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics). RIP, CGI... :(

Answer (score 1):

I feel the vast majority of 3D.SE questions would focus around the specifics of modelling / animation / rendering in a 3D modeling program.

In fact, there's probably much less overlap than between, for example, Gamedev.SE and
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=openGL

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that the site [is closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics), I guess that answers *that* question.

Comment: exactly, Nicol Bolas